# How to pass the selected value in dropdown (HTML) to PHP

Tags: php, html

I am building a select option dynamically. I am selecting from the select option, one value. (values for list come from php
How can I pass that selected value to PHP?

```
<select id ="s1" name="swimopt" class="so">
    <?php echo $options; ?>
</select>'
```

THe $options are coming from a MySQL and populating the dropdown

When I select a value, and try

`echo $_POST['swimopt'];`

does not show selected value

Please help

```
 <form id="swimdata"  method="POST" action="save.php">

     <input type="radio" style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: bolder" name="gender" class ="gender" value="boys">BOYS
     <input type="radio" style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: bolder" name="gender" class ="gender"  value="girls">GIRLS

     <table id="meetTable" style="width:auto">


    <tr>
        <th>EVENT:</th>
        <th>NAME:</th>
        <th>LANE:</th>
        <th>TIME:</th>
        <th>PLACE:</th>
        <th>SCORE 1:</th>
        <th>SCORE 2:</th>
        <th>PLACE:</th>
        <th>TIME:</th>
        <th>LANE:</th>
        <th>NAME:</th>

    </tr>

</table>

     <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
     <input type="hidden" name="action1" value="addSwimmer" id="action1">

 </form>
```

This is my PHP getting the $options from mySQL

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $options= '';
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $options .=  "<tr><td>" . $row["swimmer_id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["first_name"]. " " . $row["last_name"]. " </td><td> "  . $row["school_name"]. "</td></tr>";
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo $options;
$conn->close();
```

ScreenShots:

[image: Image of Select options in UI]

[image: List inside dropdown]

Options echoed into select box:

```
<select id ="s1" name="swimopt" class="so">
    <?php echo $options; ?>
</select>'
```

PHP file code

```
$sql = "select  first_name, last_name  from swimming where gender='m'";

$results = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    $options = '';
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        $fname=$row["first_name"];
        $lname=$row["last_name"];

        $options .= "<option value= >" . $row["first_name"] . "  " . $row["last_name"]."</option>";


    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo $options;
$link->close();


?>
```

Comment: Show your complete code ;) with form and something around your php section.

Comment: Added the form from my html file

Comment: I don't see a input with the name 'swimopt'. Have you tried `print_r($_POST)` and seeing what is even being passed?

Comment: <select id ="s1" name="swimopt" class="so">
    <?php echo $options; ?>
</select>'

Comment: Where in your form does the select reside? And as Robbie said, echo the variables on the PHP side when you submit the form. Either use `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: I have added my php code above that gets option from mySQL

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what your problem is. You're not setting a select option.
Try this:

```
<?php
$options = 'John';
?>

<form id="swimdata"  method="POST" action="save.php">

<input type="radio" style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: bolder" name="gender" class ="gender" value="boys">BOYS
<input type="radio" style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: bolder" name="gender" class ="gender"  value="girls">GIRLS

<table id="meetTable" style="width:auto">


<tr>
<th>EVENT:</th>
<th>NAME:</th>
<th>LANE:</th>
<th>TIME:</th>
<th>PLACE:</th>
<th>SCORE 1:</th>
<th>SCORE 2:</th>
<th>PLACE:</th>
<th>TIME:</th>
<th>LANE:</th>
<th>NAME:</th>

</tr>

</table>
<select id ="s1" name="swimopt" class="so" value="">
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
echo '<option value="user '.$i.'" >user '.$i.'</option>';
}
?>
</select> 
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
<input type="hidden" name="action1" value="addSwimmer" id="action1">

</form>
```

Comment: Robbie, I am getting the options from a PHP call to myMSQL, I have added the code above

Comment: Not the options. The `<option>` tags.

Comment: What data does POST say it's getting?

Comment: array (size=4)
  'gender' => string 'M' (length=4)
  'swimOpt' => string 'user10' (length=13)
  'formSubmit' => string 'Submit' (length=6)
  'action1' => string 'addSwimmer' (length=10)

Comment: It is working.
`'swimOpt' => string 'user10' (length=13)` says that it is receiving the info.

Comment: But that is not the user I selected.

Comment: Are you sure you're looping properly then? Check out the modified code above. It sounds like you may be overwriting your values.

Comment: I cant even add that to my html, doesnt like the formatting.  urgh!!

Comment: It's working fine on my side.
What error is it giving you?

Comment: In my IDE, I need to do each line ' <code>' + or I have to have it all in one line.
When I add your snippet, it does not like the ' s

Answer (score 1):

The select option must be wrapped with html tag `<option>` with a `value` attribute, which will be posted if it is selected.
According to your given code you are not generating `option`s for a `select`. So try something like this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$options= '';
// output data of each row 
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $options .=  "<option value=\"". $row["swimmer_id"] ."\">" . $row["first_name"]. " " . $row["last_name"]. " - "  . $row["school_name"]. "</option>";
}

} else {
echo "0 results";
}
echo $options;
$conn->close();
```

Now if you `$_POST` it you will get the `swimmer id`

Comment: Still get the incorrect user.
Looks like I am getting the last user each time

Comment: Add double quotes for value and escape, and this will do the same as my answer

Comment: `$options .=  "<option value=\"". $row["swimmer_id"] ."\">" . $row["first_name"]. " " . $row["last_name"]. " - "  . $row["school_name"]. "</option>";`

Comment: can you please show us the screenshot for the `<?php echo $options; ?>`, the screenshot of the DOM tree, where your options are echoed in the `<select>` box

Comment: And it will be better if you will wrap the WHOLE `<select>` box into the `$option` variable

Comment: I have added the screenshots in the initial question. Thanks

Comment: Show me the screenshot of the inspector element, not the select box itsel, i want to see how it's echoed